# Does Windows have alternatives for sigaltstack and sigaction?

Tags: c, windows

For people that don't know Linux `sigalstack` is used to create an alternate stack, for which you can read more [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaltstack.2.html). But, the basic idea can be summarized like this:

1. Allocate an area of memory to be used for the alternate signal
         stack.
2. Use `sigaltstack()` to inform the system of the existence and
         location of the alternate signal stack.
3. When establishing a signal handler using [sigaction(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/sigaction.2.html), inform the
         system that the signal handler should be executed on the alternate
         signal stack by specifying the `SA_ONSTACK` flag.

Which I basically use like this for testing a memory zeroing function.

```
#ifndef _WIN32
#define MEMZERO_STACK_SIZE              (SIGSTKSZ + sizeof(secret))
#else
#define MEMZERO_STACK_SIZE              sizeof(secret) // Maybe we need to add something here?!
#endif

// The secret that we write out to the stack. 
static const char secret[24] = {
    0x4e, 0x65, 0x76, 0x65, 0x72, 0x20, 0x67, 0x6f,
    0x6e, 0x6e, 0x61, 0x20, 0x67, 0x69, 0x76, 0x65,
    0x20, 0x79, 0x6f, 0x75, 0x20, 0x75, 0x70, 0x2c,
};

static char stack_buf[MEMZERO_STACK_SIZE];

#ifndef _WIN32
// Verify that we are on the custom stack.
static void assert_on_stack(void) {
    stack_t current_stack;
    assert(0 == sigaltstack(NULL, &current_stack));
    assert(SS_ONSTACK == (current_stack.ss_flags & SS_ONSTACK));
}

// Call the provided signal handler on a custom stack.
static void call_on_stack(void (*fn)(int)) {
    const stack_t stack = {
        .ss_sp = stack_buf,
        .ss_size = sizeof(stack_buf),
    };

    const struct sigaction action = {
        .sa_handler = fn,
        .sa_flags = SA_ONSTACK,
    };

    stack_t old_stack;
    struct sigaction old_action;

    // Setup the stack and signal handler.
    assert(0 == sigaltstack(&stack, &old_stack));
    assert(0 == sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, &old_action));

    // Raise a signal. This will only return after the signal handler has returned.
    assert(0 == raise(SIGUSR1));

    // Restore the previous state, disable our alt stack.
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &old_action, NULL);
    sigaltstack(&old_stack, NULL);
}
#endif

static char *memzero_test() {
    char buf[sizeof(secret)];
    char *result;

    assert_on_stack();

    memcpy(buf, secret, sizeof(secret));
    result = memmem(stack_buf, MEMZERO_STACK_SIZE, buf, sizeof(buf));

    memset(buf, 0, sizeof(buf));   
    return result;
}

static void memzero_test_correctness_signal_handler(int arg)
{
   // Removed for brevity. It calls memzero_test here, and basically
   // when this function finishes execution a signal is sent to the 
   // call_on_stack function.
   char *buf = memzero_test();
   if (memcmp(buf, secret, sizeof(secret)) != 0) {
      printf("Test passed\n");
    } else {
      printf("Test failed\n");
    }
}

call_on_stack(memzero_test_correctness_signal_handler);
```

So, I want to test it also in Windows, but Windows of course does not support these GNU C Library specific data types and constants. Hence, I need another method to rewrite it, more specifically create a custom stack, execute a function on it, and inform when the function finishes, so as to clear it. Any ideas how to do that in Windows?

Comment: Signals are generally not they way to handle asynchronous events on Windows, and therefore it's going to be very hard to translate almost anything relating to POSIX signals to Windows (without a POSIX compatibility layer). For a better Windows solution it really depends on what you're attempting to do, what problem you're trying to solve, your use-case, but typically Windows message and message loop could possibly be used (you don't need a GUI app to have a message Windows loop).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the info. Like in my code sample, I just want a secret written to some "stack", which I can later try to erase, and see whether it is actually erased. So, how can I use Windows message and message loop for my case here?

Comment: `printf("Test passed\n");`?  You're not actually calling `printf()` in a signal handler, are you?  `printf()` is not async-signal-safe.

Comment: @AndrewHenle There is another function in between, I just tried to put here the relevant segments. But all my printf work correctly. In Linux my signal stack code work nicely. The point is how can I achieve something similar in Windows.

Comment: signal is a linux(*nix or wtf else) term . Assembler(own OS) doesn't have it so as windows.on sdk level Windows has `hooks` for this.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин Thanks. Code sample would be highly welcome.

Comment: i didnt catch your goal with handler. For exploit protection may be it's better to use `openssl`.

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин that’s just Linux way of creating a custom stack and executing a function on it. I agree the signal naming is a bit confusing, but it is named so as when the callback function returns it raises a signal so you can clear the newly allocated stack. But the whole idea is call a function on a custom stack. No events triggered or anything.

Comment: Deja-vu?   Have you not already asked this question once?

Comment: @MartinJames It was slightly different. I made this one so as to include more info and make it more explicit.

Comment: idk about alternative stack options in windows. cpu may load only one address to sp register anyway , meanwhile alternative stuff would be in heap i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The supported way of running multiple stacks in Windows is [fibers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ProcThread/fibers).

However I’m not sure this is the right approach for your task. If you want to wipe a secret when you get an event, call [SecureZeroMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the event handler.

Comment: I’m testing various secure erasing techniques, so I have a function pointer that iterates through different functions and erases, so I test each of them. I just use a custom stack as not to interfere with the main stack of the app. Can you give a code example as how it would be with fibers?

Comment: One caveat is that in memzero_test function I make use of the stack_buf array as that is the stack buffer in my Linux code. So somehow fiber stack and stack_buf array should point to same place or I need to somehow restructure the code for a fiber.

Comment: If I were you I would not use fibers. Write a singleton class or global functions to register & unregister the buffers, keeping pointers to them in a central location. If you use C++, write a RAII class to register/unregister stack allocated or stack owned buffers. This way, when you’ll get the event, you can wipe all buffers allocated by all functions in your app, regardless on where are they.  If your code is multithreaded (e.g. because your event arrives to different thread) you need a mutex in register & unregister functions. It’s also a good idea to wipe buffers when unregistered.

Comment: I think the signal word that I used above is a bit misleading. There is no events triggering it or something. I simple have the call call_on_stack(memzero_test_correctness_signal_handler) on my main. And what the call_on_stack does that it creates a “signal stack”, and executes the passed function on that new stack. And when the callback function finishes, it just raises a signal that it is finished and clears the newly allocated stacked. So there is no specific event calling the call_on_stack function, it just gets called inside main. It’s just a Linux way of doing things.

Comment: Windows way is different. You only getting asynchronous events using 3 methods. You can get them explicitly, e.g. when you calls GetMessage or GetQueuedCompletionStatus. Some callbacks arrive while the thread is sleeping on SleepEx or WaitForSingleObjectEx, OS calls your handlers from inside, on the same stack. Or, you can get them on another OS thread, on different stack.

Comment: `on different stack`, this is what I need. I think my Linux code confused people more than I thought. Let's forget it for a moment. Here is what I want to achieve, and from what I read fibers may be a good option. I need to have a custom stack, and that custom stack needs to store `secret` array. Then, I call the `memzero_test` function on this custom stack. I check using `memmem` (I have this, as by default Windows doesn't have it), which gives where the `secret` array values begins, I erase that portion from stack, and test whether it was erased. Once test finish, new stack goes away.

Comment: @terett If it’s just for that single buffer, single stack + heap-allocated buffer is IMO way easier to implement. But if you want secondary stack to be able to wipe **all** local variables on that stack, fibers might actually work for that. `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` API returns correct stack range, here’s a test: https://gist.github.com/Const-me/9c5ea55b1341ffd46cfda16ec891a269

Comment: Thanks for the code sample. How can I write data to the stack of fiber?

Comment: Cool, thanks. One final question is whether one can get reference to the fiber’s stack? Let’s say I want a pointer to point to the same location as fiber’s stack?

Comment: From the inside. Call `GetCurrentThreadStackLimits` API like I have in my sample. If you gonna wipe the whole range, pass that to other fiber and make sure you never switch to the wiped fiber ever again.

Comment: After SwitchToFiber, the current stack stops running completely. Possibly forever. To get fiber’s stack location, you have to call GetCurrentThreadStackLimits from that another fiber. When you’re done with the fiber, call SwitchToFiber to resume execution of the main stack. To do that, you have to save main fiber pointer (the result of ConvertThreadToFiber() call) somewhere the second fiber can read from, e.g. in a global variable. Also you can’t provide custom buffer for stack, it’s allocated by OS, and is destroyed by DeleteFiber. Finally, the fiber returns void not DWORD.